# 2003 Honda Civic LX won't start

Tags: electrical, honda, civic

My car will not start and when I do turn the key forward to a certain point the 5 pin main relay starts clicking rapidly and the automatic transmission shift lever solenoid goes crazy with the plunger going in/out rapidly also the dash lights start flickering. There isn't any power to anything else and when I tried turning the headlights on it start making a weird buzzing noise without the lights coming on. So far I've replaced the main relays and ignition switch with no results.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the battery? properly charged and the connections and terminals? I would start there.

Then, check all the earths or grounds between engine / body, engine / battery and body / battery as the next step. Then you are probably into looking at the feeds from the battery to the major components and controls.

Comment: yes, i replaced the battery, checked the connections and terminals after cleaning them with no results

Comment: Is there some event that happened with this vehicle lately? Like floating around in Houston?

Comment: What is the voltage measured over the battery terminals at the moment of all of this craziness?

Comment: @MaSlo as it is nearly a year ago, you would think the OP has either solved it or dumped it ...